# Global HTTP Proxy always prompts for username and password

Tags: ios, iphone, proxy, http-proxy, apple-configurator

My task is to set the Global Proxy on device. For testing purposes I've installed the `GlobalProxy.mobileconfig` on supervised iPhone 7 (iOS 11.4.1) using **Apple Configurator**. I have specified the ProxyUsername and ProxyPassword, but I keep on getting prompts to enter username/password.

**Why credentials from mobileconfig are being ignored?**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>PayloadContent</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>PayloadDescription</key>
            <string>Global HTTP Proxy</string>
            <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
            <string>Global HTTP Proxy</string>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.proxy.http.global.F1520526-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX</string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>com.apple.proxy.http.global</string>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>F1520526-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>ProxyCaptiveLoginAllowed</key>
            <false/>
            <key>ProxyPassword</key>
            <string>THE_PROXY_PASSWORD</string>
            <key>ProxyServer</key>
            <string>XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX</string>
            <key>ProxyServerPort</key>
            <integer>443</integer>
            <key>ProxyType</key>
            <string>Manual</string>
            <key>ProxyUsername</key>
            <string>THE_USER_NAME</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
    <string>GlobalProxyByAppleConfigurator</string>
    <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
    <string>My-MacBook.EB8C7563-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX</string>
    <key>PayloadRemovalDisallowed</key>
    <false/>
    <key>PayloadType</key>
    <string>Configuration</string>
    <key>PayloadUUID</key>
    <string>231BDE9B-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX</string>
    <key>PayloadVersion</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |

Comment: Mark, im facing the same issue.  You found a solution?